# Is there a loop that will exclued variable when the variable is null while echoing to a webpage in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am pulling information from a mysql db as an Associative Array. Some variables will be NULL if there is no information (i.e. a phone number or a second address line). I extract the information and echo it to a webpage just fine. However, the positions which hold return Null there is a blank. I would like to remove the blank for those records which are NULL.

I have tried to create a foreach statement to loop through the array, but it repeats the records 14 times in a row excluding one variable at a time.

**Example:**

***A database has 10 columns:***

```
    id = auto increment 
    fname
    lname
    address1
    address2 = NULL
    city
    state
    zip
    officephone = NULL
    mobilephone = NULL
```

**Class::members();**

***After running my PDO, I begin a while loop and create the array $member:***

```
   while($return = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $member = array(
              $return['fname'],
              $return['lname'],
              $return['address1'],
              $return['address2'],
              $return['city'],
              $return['state'],
              $return['zip'],
              $return['ophone'],
              $return['mphone']);
```

***I echo this to the webpage with html and css styling***

```
      echo 

          $member[1] . $member[2].'<br />' .
          $member[3] . '<br />'.
          $member[4] . '<br />'.
          $member[5] . ', ' . $member[6].$member[7].'<br />'.
          $member[8] . '<br />' .
          $member[9] . '<br />'.
```

***What is looks like on the web page***

***Instantiating - this runs through the records until the end then stops.***

```
    <?php $abs = array(Class::members()); foreach($mbs as $mb) { echo $mb;}?>
```

**What you see**

```
    John Smith
    222 One Drive
                   (GAP BECAUSE NULL)
    Somewhere, USA 00000
                   (GAP BECAUSE NULL)
    555555555
```

***I want to write some php code to skip the GAP above when it is NULL, but include it when it is not NULL.***

***So that it looks like:***

```
    John Smith
    222 One Drive
    Somewhere, USA 00000
    555555555
```

***I have tried creating a method to loop through the results and skip the NULL variable with no success.***

```
    foreach($member as $key => $value)

    /* variants I have tried in if() statment ($value != NULL), 
    ($value === NULL),($value == 'NULL'), ($value == ""), 
    (empty($value)), ($member[$value] == NULL)*/

    if($value == NULL) {
    continue; }
    }
```

***This returns 14 identical results of each record, and all of them have a gap. I have also tried to use array_filter($members).***

**Any recommendations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not output `<BR>` when not needed:

```
$output = $member[1] . $member[2];
$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[3];
$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[4];
$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[5];
$output.= ($output!='' AND ($member[6]!='' OR $member[7]!='') ? ', ' : '') . $member[6] . $member[7];
$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[8];
$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[9];
echo $output;
```

---

## UPDATE (11 April 2019)

I think this is a better solution to your challenge:

```
$output = $member[1] . $member[2];
$output.= ($output!='' ? "\n" : '') . $member[3];
$output.= ($output!='' ? "\n" : '') . $member[4];
$output.= ($output!='' ? "\n" : '') . $member[5];
$output.= ($output!='' AND ($member[6]!='' OR $member[7]!='') ? ', ' : '') . $member[6] . $member[7];
$output.= ($output!='' ? "\n" : '') . $member[8];
$output.= ($output!='' ? "\n" : '') . $member[9];

// we replace multiple NewLines with a single NewLine
$output = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", $output);
// we trim our string to remove the NewLines on left and write, if any
$output = trim($output);
// we then simply replace all NewLines with <BR>
echo nl2br($output);
```

Comment: I like this format, however, I still have the same issue. It does still echo the BR tag, and the GAP. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, to prevent $output from repeating the output twice, I set $output = ''.

Comment: What are the values inside `$member` array which cause the above code to show unnecessary BRs ?

Comment: ````$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[8];```` is a phone number that may be there or it may not be there.

Comment: when I do ```echo var_dump()``` I get ```string(0) ""```  for the missing phone number and ```string(11) " 5555555555"``` when the phone number is there.

Comment: I figured it out. Your recommendation was ```$output.= ($output!='' ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[8]``` I added ```$output.= ($output!= !$member[8] ? '<br/>' : '') . $member[8]``` and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help! I have not worked much with  ternary operators, but that is going to change.

Comment: I basically looked at the syntax for the if/else statement and saw the !$variable which means NOT.

Comment: I updated my answer with a supposedly better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `array_filter()` to remove the **Null**'s from your `$member` array like this-

```
$member = array_filter($member);
```

It'll remove boolean `false`, null, `''` from your array value if exists. [SEE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). If you want to restrict the value you can use any **callback** function.

Comment: It doesn't remove the GAP. it returned the same information and included an error "Undefined offset: 10" (10 is where the GAP is located).